# Team Explorer can't resolve git local repository which was migrated by VSS2Git

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-sourcesafe

I was trying to migrate/upgrade a solution(Database project) from VSS to Git.

After a few operations(like disconnect the source control, upgrade project file, etc), I found out the most of the options in team explorer are gone.
[image]

Now there is only Settings left but there suppose to have Changes, Braches, Sync. Like
[image]

And the worst is, I thought it's because I messed up something in the solution(local repository) but I found out that all repositories now behave the same when I open them by Visual studio.

What should I do to fix this situation?

Answer (score 0):

<s>It seems perhaps one of my operations disconnect me from Git instead of VSS cause those options resume after I reconnect to TFS Git proactively.</s>

I ran into the same problem again. It seems VSS2Git somehow dis-attached the repo from Team Explorer so you can see it shows Offline caption right after Home.

Solution
1. In Team Explorer, switch to connect tab.
2. Under local git repositories clicks Add and select the repo you want.
3. Double click the repo you picked in the previous step to attach it.
4. Now you should be able to have correct home page with repo you are targeting.

After steps above, if you lost entries in Solution Explorer, means the VSS didn't unbind fully by VSS. Try the following

1. File > Source Control > Change Source Control
2. Unbind project which still sticks with VSS